# Odd & Even Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

If you have a range of numbers from 1-49 with 6 numbers to choose from, how many combinations are there containing all odd, all even, only 1 odd, and only 1 even number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 6 odd combinations:

$$\ _{25}C_6 / _{49}C_6 = 177100/13983816 $$

All 6 even combinations:

$$\ _{24}C_6 / _{49}C_6 = 134596/13983816 $$

Only 1/6 odd combinations:

$$\ _{25}C_5 * 24 / _{49}C_6 = 1275120/13983816 $$

Only 1/6 even combinations:

$$\ _{24}C_5 * 25 / _{49}C_6 = 1062600/13983816 $$

I use choose rather than pick because you do not want repeats.

Comment: The number of selections is requested, not the probability.  Also, even if you were supposed to calculate the probabilities, your last two answers would still be wrong since six numbers are selected, the selection of one odd number means that five even numbers are selected, and the selection of one even number means five odd numbers are selected.

Comment: The question was edited, my response applies to the old question.  Thank you for pointing out the flaws in the second two answers, I will fix them.

Answer (score 0):

There are $25$ odd and $24$ even numbers in the range $1 - 49$.

The number of selections of six numbers from the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 49\}$ that contain exactly $k$ odd numbers and $6 - k$ even numbers is 
$$\binom{25}{k}\binom{24}{6 - k}$$

> Therefore, the number of selections that contain just odd numbers is $$\binom{25}{6}\binom{24}{0} = \binom{25}{6}$$ The number of selections that contain just even numbers is $$\binom{25}{0}\binom{24}{6} = \binom{24}{6}$$  Selections that contain exactly one odd number must contain five even numbers.  The number of such selections is $$\binom{25}{1}\binom{24}{5}$$  Selections that contain exactly one even number must contain five odd numbers.  The number of such selections is $$\binom{25}{5}\binom{24}{1}$$