# Probability formula - combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have been building a JavaScript engine that calculates possibilities. Following this [post about odd and even numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3248033/odd-even-combinations), I would like to ask what is the formula that produces the possible combinations and probability if we choose e.g. 8 numbers in 45/5 game.

(e.g. the possible combinations in 45/5 game are 1.221.759, and if I choose 3 odd numbers out of 23 in [1-45] range and 2 even from the rest 22, it gives a total of 409.101 combinations, that is 33.48% of the total. But what if I want to choose 8 or 10 numbers (let's say 5 odd and 5 even) in the same 45/5 game? I am searching for the formula that produces the percentage of playing more numbers than the absolutely required.)

Thanks in advance :)
Daniel

Comment: I have never heard such a thing as "the 45/5 game", and I am surely not alone. Could you give a good reference ?

Comment: In Greece, it is called Joker, and it is a differentiation of Powerball or Euromillions. The draw consists of 5 drawn numbers from 1-45, and then from a different pool of numbers, one from 1-20 that is called the Joker. So the basic playing consists of 5 numbers from 1-45 and 1 from 1-20.

(Saw my mistake. It is 5/45, not 45/5).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.